# when i console req.body it,s give me all property with value but when i get single property value it,s give me error undefined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, body-parser

i am working on angular and nodejs i registering new user from angular side data properly goes to nodejs side but in nodejs side when i console req.body it,s give me properties with value but when i want to get single property value it,s give me error undefined 
this is my index.js

```
   const express = require('express');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const cors = require('cors');
   //this line is use to connect with mongodb
   const {mongoose} = require('./db.js');

  var userController = require('./controllers/userController.js');

 const app = express();

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use(cors({ origin : 'http://localhost:4200' })); 
// it,s listening port 3000  
 app.listen(3000,() => { console.log('app listen port : 3000'); });

//here is the user operation start   
app.use('/user',userController); //end of the user operation
```

this is my userController file

```
 router.post('/',(req,res) => {
 var newUser = new User({
  firstName:req.body.firstName,
  firstLast:req.body.lastName,
  emailAddress:req.body.emailAddress,
  passowrd:req.body.password,
  user_role:2,
  account_status:1,
});

 var recordExist = false;

 User.findOne({emailAddress:req.body.emailAddress},(error,doc) => {
   if(doc)
   recordExist = true;
   else
   console.log('there is an error to get record with given email :' + req.body.emailAddress);

 });

res.send(req.body.emailAddress);

});
```

when i console req.body it,s give me everything ok properties with values
but when i console req.body.emailAddress it,s give me undefined

```
   firstName: "abubakkar", lastName: "khan", emailAddress: 
   "abubakkar.tahir.khan@gmail.com", password: "12345"} firstName: 
   "abubakkar" lastName: "khan" emailAddress: "abubakkar.tahir.khan@gmail.com" password: "12345"
```

Comment: Can you post your `req.body`??

Comment: export interface Users {
    _id :string;
    firstName:String;
    firstLast:String;
    emailAddress:String;
    passowrd:String;
    user_role:Number;
    account_status:Number;
}

Comment: Paste your `req.body` in the question what it has

Comment: Its weird that if you executed `User.findOne({emailAddress:req.body.emailAddress}` query successfully means you are able to get data right??

Comment: it,s does not give me result give me empty result

Comment: Paste your `req.body` exactly. What you have pasted doesn't make sense.

Comment: it,s not excuted      User.findOne({emailAddress:req.body.emailAddress},(error,doc) => {
       if(doc)
       recordExist = true;
       else
       console.log('there is an error to get record with given email :' + req.body.emailAddress);

    }); what is the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204541/discussion-between-abubakkar-tahir-and-subburaj).

Comment: If you're using Postmon to send requests, make sure to choose `JSON` in the `Body`. The default `Text` wouldn't work and will give out this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the req.body to JSON

```
req.body = JSON.parse(req.body) 
console.log(req.body.emailAddress) // now it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact problem, and I realized that the problem was with my client side fetch function. It could be that the request you are making is causing the problem. I was missing the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header in my request. When you forget to add this `req.body` is a string. If you include the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header in your request then you should have an object in `req.body`.

```js
// client request

fetch("/api/route", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ content: "foo" }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
)
```

Then in express you should be able to get

```js
console.log(req.body.content)

\\ output: "foo"
```